# Что правильно использовать? Класс row или row-fluid при верстки responsive шаблона Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: responsive, bootstrap

Помогите,пожалуйста, разобраться какой класс **row** или **row-fluid** нужно указывать в container при верстки responsive шаблона  на **bootstrap 2.3.2**
Для примера смотрел несколько шаблонов в некоторых используется row, а в некоторых row-fluid при этом container в обоих случаях без fluid (как и должно быть,так как интересует НЕ резиновый, а **responsive**)
bootstrap-responsive.css подключен всегда.

**Что правильно для responsive row или row-fliud?**

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" style="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" style="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">       
    <div class="row-fluid">

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: soledar10, спасибо  за отклик на вопрос, но ваш вариант верстки макета получился полностью резиновый т.е. fluid. На мониторах 1920*1080 макет растягивается на всю ширину =>1920px
Поэтому, скорее всего правильный ответ, будет container БЕЗ fluid, а вот row-fluid и подключенный bootstrap-responsive.css обязательно. Я правда на 100% не уверен, но 95% так. Ждем однозначного решения ответа от профессионалов в bootstrap.
soledar10, за ответ спасибо.

Comment: так это зависит от того какой вам сайт нужен - т.е от и до

Comment: Нужен на bootstrap 2.3.2, responsive, но не на всю ширину экрана. То есть НЕ резиновый, а только responsive. В этом случае какими должны быть классы container и row ? Есть мнение  :-) что container должен быть обычтным, а вот row все fluid. Хотя в некоторых шаблонах есть ошибка или недочет на это счет: http://bootswatch.com/2/cerulean/ например, имеет недочет в части использования row.

Comment: если так используйте container

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
Итог:
для Bootsrap 2.3.2 и макет responsive (НЕ резиновый), используем container (без fluid),а row-fluid (row с fluid).
Разжевал для всех кто будет читать данный вопрос и ответы